# How to use xlim to set different index at X-axis in R while plotting the graph?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot the graph for every hour of a 1 week time series.  The X-axis should look like:

```
0  1  2  3  4 .....23  0  1  2 3 4....23  0 1  2  3 ....23............ 0  1  2  3 ...23
---Monday----          ------Tuesday----  ----Wedneday----.............-----Sunday-----
```

I don't know how to set the xlim for that because I need the x-axis for each hour representation for 1 week. There will be 168 points (24*7=168) on the x-axis altogether.

Comment: In what form are your data?

Comment: data is in numeric like: For Monday at 00:00 hr values is 12344,at 01:00hr values is 234535.....Similarly for every day in a week.Hope I have answered you. If not let me know I will elaborate it more.

Comment: Help us out here. Why should those values be one hour apart? 234535-12344 = 222191

Comment: It is because I have collected some data on hourly basis for one week and I want to plot the graph for that.So I have 24*7 that means total 168 values are there.Daniel have given approximate answer please look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but my solution to the same problem was to use ggplot2... and overplot by day of the week - which showed me that Sat and Sun were distinct, but the other days of week were very similar in behaviour.

```
# some random data...
adf <- data.frame(day.of.week=rep(c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'), 24),
      hour.of.day=rep(1:24, 7), y.to.be.plotted=runif(168))
qplot(hour.of.day, y.to.be.plotted, data=adf, colour=day.of.week, geom='line')
library(ggplot2)
qplot(as.integer(hour.of.day), y.to.be.plotted, data=my.data,
        colour=day.of.week, geom='line')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will go through you process and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

If there are 168 points, just set it to `xlim=c(0,168)`, suppress the axis and label it separately, e.g.

```
plot(...,xlim=c(0,168),xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=c(1:168),rep(1:24,7))
```

The x-axis might be a bit full that way, so maybe you want only to annotate every 6th hours or so. And then you recode the data in a way that the timepoints match, something like "hours since beginning" or so.

Comment: Thank You so much....this is not the exact way what I need but somehow it's working.I guess I will able to do it now by some modification with given your above references and I will update my solution once I will solve it.Thank you again :)